# Why can't I pull and calculate user form input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, label, getelementbyid

I am building a volume calculator for a website, however, I cannot seem to get the user input from the form to pull into Javascript and calculate the volume. It generates no output.

```js
function calculate() {
    var x = 0;
    var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById("length").value) * 12;
    var width = parseFloat(document.getElementById("width").value) * 12;
    var depth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("depth").value);
    if (document.getElementById("square").checked)
    {
        x = (length * width * depth) / 12;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("circle").checked)
    {
        x = (Math.PI * length * width * depth / 4) / 12;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Type:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="square" checked> Cubic<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="circle"> Cylinder<br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Length: <br />
                        (in feet)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="length">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Width:  <br />
                        (in feet)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="width">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Depth: <br />
                        (in Inches) 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="depth">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <button onclick="calculate()"><font color="#979189">Calculate</font></button>

        <label id="result"> </label> Cubic Feet

        <script>
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The script should output the calculation into a label but nothing seems to happen. When I attempt to output the data directly to the label from the form field:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("length").value;
```

It also does not show any output. Would anyone happen to see what I am missing here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you run the code it shows an error in the console that you are trying to access an element with id of square or circle that is not present and these are the radio buttons. You should give them either ids or handle them in some other way: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/radio_buttons.html

Comment: Wow, i feel dumb. Thank you for pointing that out, I can't believe I missed something that obvious.

Comment: Don't be, mate. We do all kinds of mistakes. That is why we have each others back on stackoverflow ;)

I believe there are better formatted answers out there, sorry, I was in a rush.

Answer (score 3):

There are no elements with the ID `circle` or `square`, only those values

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="square" checked> Cubic
<input type="radio" name="type" value="circle"> Cylinder
```

which means you can't do

```
document.getElementById("square").checked
```

Just give them the correct ID

```
<input id="square" type="radio" name="type" value="square" checked> Cubic
<input id="circle" type="radio" name="type" value="circle"> Cylinder
```

and it should work -> [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ue5zhqkn/)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("square")` 
and 
`document.getElementById("circle")` could not have been resolved because you missed the Id on the Inputs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Type:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="square" id="square" checked> Cubic<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="circle" id="circle"> Cylinder<br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Length: <br />
                        (in feet)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="length">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Width:  <br />
                        (in feet)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="width">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Depth: <br />
                        (in Inches) 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="depth">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <button onclick="calculate()"><font color="#979189">Calculate</font></button>

        <label id="result"> </label> Cubic Feet

        <script>
            function calculate() {
                var x = 0;
                var length =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("length").value) * 12;
                var width =  parseFloat(document.getElementById("width").value) * 12;
                var depth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("depth").value);
                if ( document.getElementById("square").checked )
                {
                    x = (length * width * depth) / 12;
                }
                else if ( document.getElementById("circle").checked )
                {
                    x = (Math.PI * length * width * depth / 4) / 12;
                }
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```